# How to debug ggplot in browser mode within shiny?

Tags: debugging, ggplot2, plot, shiny

We used to check the reactive value using **browser** but 
when ggplot is not rendering expected graph, how can we debug this in reactive mode ?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    browser() # Here, the browser stops but when run the below line, cannot see the plot in plots tab
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg) # or ggplot ...both not rendering plot in browser mode
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you can ask for a new device to open:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7460
Called from: renderPlot(...)
Browse[1]> plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg) ## won't plot
Browse[1]> dev.new() ## opens a new window
Browse[1]> plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg) ## now plots
```

Comment: perfect solution. you saved days of rework :) Thanks a ton. 
Also, due to your solution....Now, debugged ggplot error also :)